# Remove app label on navigation drawer activity (main) and other all activity

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, titlebar

I am using navigation drawer activity in my app and I add nice logo on title bar .
I want to remove app name on tittle. I try a lot of code. I don't want to use

```
Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar
```

Comment: Did you use toolbar ?

Comment: are you mean is custom toolbar?

Comment: isn't there anything like `getActionBar().setTitle("")` ?

Comment: i try it but my app forced close

Comment: yes @SobhanMoradi , And can you please share the layout file's code ?

Answer (score 4):

Try following  line it may be work.

```
getActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
```

or

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
```

Comment: Thank you so much frined. The getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
worked

Answer (score 0):

in style.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowEnableSplitTouch">false</item>
    <item name="android:splitMotionEvents">false</item>
</style>
```

in androidmainfest

```
 <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
```

Try it!

Answer (score 0):

In AndroidManifest.xml

```
 <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label=""
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
        android:configChanges="screenSize|orientation">
    </activity>
```

in styles.xml add below code

```
 <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```